# pick and drop weapon in unity 3d mobile fps

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, 3d

please who ,now to create a ui button for pick and drop for a 3D mobile game tel me because I search lot of in youtube , google but I didn't find . please who now the answer tel me.

hello everybody , please who ,now to create a ui button for pick and drop for a 3D mobile game tel me because I search lot of in youtube , google but I didn't find .

Comment: Please elaborate on what you intend to accomplish. What does "Pick and Drop" mean? Can you add some code to show what you have done?

Comment: i don't know what i write in the scripts